# Spring Security, programmatic login for json restful web service

Tags: spring-security

I am using spring 4.2.1 with spring security 4.0.2

On login, I need to return a json object tree to the client, containing the cached data it requires for the session.

So I've added a the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ServerResponse<?> login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword());

    Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);

    Object data = null; // Do stuff here

    return new ServerResponse<>(data);
}
```

My spring security config:

```
<ss:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">

    <ss:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <!-- this is enabled by default in spring 4 -->
    <ss:csrf disabled="true" />

    <ss:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthFilter" />

    <ss:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" />

    <ss:port-mappings>
        <ss:port-mapping http="8080" https="8443" />
    </ss:port-mappings>

    <ss:intercept-url pattern="/app/logi**" access="permitAll()" />
    <ss:intercept-url pattern="/app/logou**" access="permitAll()" />

    <ss:intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="hasAuthority('user')" />
    <ss:intercept-url pattern="/www/**" access="hasAuthority('user')" />
</ss:http>
```

All the pages I find regarding a programmatic login confirm that what I am doing is fine.

However, when I try and call another web service method later, I get 403 as the client is not logged in.

I read some vague references to having to use a spring filter, but I am not sure how I would get the filter to return the json tree to the client after successful login.

Any suggestions or links to an example on how to do this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooo it turns out the problem was that I was doing Cross Origin Resource Sharing and the browser was not sending the cookie across with the next request.

Basically I was calling the server from html on the file system (with origin file://)

I was handling options calls, but I was not sending back

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
```

headers in the responses and I had to configure angular to send the cookie by passing the flag

```
withCredentials: true
```

in the config object to $http.post